# 1 user reposting same question over and over

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

This user (https://stackoverflow.com/users/3573907/user3573907) has posted the same question over the last few days at least 5 times.

Closing as duplicates of each other is one solution. However it seems like a better solution would be to just delete the duplicates entirely, and interact with the user from a "moderator" level to let them know firmly that this is not right.

I have flagged one of the questions as "other" with an explanation, but I know the mods are overworked, and don't like to take the time to investigate strange comments like that.

So what is one to do here? Is this the right way to highlight and ask for mod intervention?

---

This is probably a dupe, but I can't find it with the search.

---

I suspect this question ([Why the notification do not appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732296/why-the-notification-do-not-appear)) might be by the same guy, but there's no way for me to know. It looks like a dupe, which I discovered only after answering it. It is using the exact same code as the other posts fwiw.

Comment: Wow, notifications must be haunting him even in nightmares, by the look of his question

Comment: *"but I know the mods are overworked, and don't like to take the time to investigate strange comments like that."* ... the latter part most certainly isn't true. Never hesitate to flag a situation like that.

Comment: @bart that's why I did. But there is a lot of discussion on meta about this type of thing, and how specific one must be regarding flags etc. Recently flags were turned down due to not being specific enough, and requireing mod investigation. (or so I claim - I have just tried to find the posts I'm suggesting, but have failed)

Comment: It's a self-limiting problem - the user will trigger the question limit pretty soon (I assume). However, I went through and linked the duplicates to the first (I think) version of that question and [left a comment to point the user in the right direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23661699/how-to-create-android-notification-after-compare-the-current-date-with-the-store#comment36482056_23661699).

Comment: Like a monkey with a miniature cymbal.

Comment: Had a similar issue in the PHP tag recently. I flagged it and the mods took care of them.

Comment: I bet, that some people just found out how to freak out high rep users and simply have fun to do that ^_^

Comment: @DamienPirsy      i understand i have reposted the question many times..honestly i just haven't got any relevant answers to this plus i was so desperate to get that answer...KINDLY HELP ME GET AN ANSWER

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Don't be concerned about it - the community will do its job by closing them as duplicates and down voting where necessary (this has already happened, especially since you gave it some sunlight).

Once he trips certain thresholds he will be automatically post banned by the Community ♦ user. He will also show up in various tools (reports) the moderators have access to. It is unlikely that his behaviour will continue for much longer.

Comment: thx - do the tools include a way to deduce if the other link I ended up answering is by the same "anonymous" user?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Yes the mods do have tools for that sort of thing. It may well be the same user, although he appears to have made a lot more effort as the second user you linked to. He may already be post banned hence his second account.

Comment: @AD7six to the best of my knowledge, the IP-level ban isn't immediate and only used in extreme cases because of the side effects (effectively banning everyone else at the company or school, or anyone else inheriting that IP with a dynamic IP host).  It is just as possible as it is the same user as it is someone else in the class

Comment: I should have said just-as-likely; I know nothing about SE's ban implementations. In any case though: if it's the same person, it won't be in their interest to have two accounts =).

Comment: How is the situation handled when the original question doesn't have upvoted/accepted answers? This happened today: the same Q was posted twice and the first one was put on hold and has no answers.