# Should I raise a flag for user asking the same question over and over?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts

Basically [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6608272/chetan-sarode) has asked the same low quality question over and over (with slight variations). Ultimately it boils down to *how do I use ajax with asp.net*.

But each time he's had no response he's just asked the same question again, with some tweaks. I've downvoted and voted to close most of the questions (I should have used duplicate flags I think but I didn't notice at first).

**Is this worthy of flagging to a mod** or should I just let my close votes do their work?

**Am I going to get grabbed for serial voting here?** I suppose I kinda have serially downvoted, but because I think the questions are poor not because I have an issue with the user.

Comment: I would drop an informative comment explaining to OP that it's helpful for them to keep asking again and again the same question in different posts, and instead they should focus on improving their post to meet the minimal standards of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Cool. I've tried to add some helpful comments without getting on the OPs back too much. Ultimately his problem is a lack of understanding. No one can help him learn when he's not willing to figure some of it out himself.

Comment: If the user keeps on doing this, he will eventually be banned from questions *automatically*.

Comment: See also: [1 user reposting same question over and over](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255371/21960)

Comment: @MarounMaroun Did you mean: ***it's not helpful***

Comment: IIRC an automatic flag is raised when a user asks the same question again and again.

Comment: Gold tag badgers have the ability to close these kinds of questions immediately as dupes of the earlier ones.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I believe that's the exception case as in any duplicate closure of one post to another post by the *same* OP is allowed. You're not allowed to close a post as duplicate as another if it doesn't have answers or an accepted answer.

Comment: Right, "same author" is the one exception to the "must be answered" rule.

Comment: @JoshCaswell correct - having a diamond over-rides that rule - but that's rarely the case  for the time I've held one and needed to use it in such cases.

Comment: @dorukayhan Sure, thanks.

Comment: Other than flagging [Nothing!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323749/individuals-flooding-the-site-with-off-topic-too-broad-questions-that-show-no-ef).

Comment: @Glorfindel - no they will not, unless multiple users down vote their content it will just continue, and *"organizing a mob down vote on a user"* is not allowed no matter how objectively poor their content is. If it is a narrow tag or slow tag, they will never get enough down votes organically to trigger anything in the system. And the promotion of the general idea that *down voting is mean* and the general apathy from those that can close vote. The trash is just piles up and the system never gives any negative feedback to the user.

Comment: nothing to draw a flood of downvotes like a good ol' meta question to validate your view