# User asks similar question over and over again - flag declined

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

In the last 24 hours a user is posting same (at least *very* similar) question over and over again, using similar code: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53600061/6574038), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53607781/6574038), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53609193/6574038), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53611246/6574038), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53612935/6574038), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53615890/6574038). Several users already complained about this behavior. I have flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53615890/6574038) for moderator attention and linked to the [landing page of user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10740461/dado) to provide the summary of his/her recent posts.

Now my flag was declined with kinda request in comment to provide links:

[image]

As requested in flag comment I provide the links to duplicated posts here (I didn't dare to flag again).

From an [earlier meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255374/6574038) I learn that an equivalent flag at least wasn't *un*-helpful, so i don't exactly understand why the flag was *declined*. How should we / shouldn't we flag such cases?

Comment: Because custom flags take a bit more to process, you're going to want to provide *as much context as possible in the flag itself*.  Just saying that this user is doing X without showing what they're doing is a good way to generate a false positive like this.  I don't think you're in the wrong for flagging these but devoid of the context in the flag that you've provided in *this* Meta post, I could see why they're declined.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, so if I understood correctly: Flag was ok, in the future only all links are to be provided, as I did it here and not only to link to the user's landing page with the summary.

Comment: If these questions are duplicates then you should be voting to close as such. There doesn’t need to be an answer in this case since they’re all by the same person.

Comment: @Laurel At six duplicates of the exact same question, that goes beyond just meriting closing as duplicates and gets to a point where there's a good argument for moderator intervention.  At just one or two, you'd be right, but at some point it becomes a difference of degree such that a mod should get involved.

Comment: @Servy I guess I wasn’t really clear: you should do both. Moderator intervention is usually slow and you don’t want people to try to give answers. Unfortunately at this point it looks like seven people did so.

Comment: @Laurel Agreed.

Comment: What should we as users do here?  My first inclination is to downvote and VTC all of the linked questions because they do not seem useful and are borderline spam.  However, I'd rather not get flagged for potentially targeting a specific user.

Comment: For the record dado is a character on the SCP-Wiki at http://www.scp-wiki.net/dado-hub. This may be a pure coincidence but it may be worth it to investigate possible trolling behavior.

Comment: The greater problem here is that when it is so cheap/low effort creating lots of users, bad actors do neither have an incentive, nor there is enforcement so to speak, for them to behave properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the flagging system doesn't allow discussions with the moderator reviewing the flag. Note that you don't even know *who* handled the flag.

So basically the moderator asks you to flag again with more information (and they probably lack the time to visit user profile to investigate). The flag isn't useful since nothing came out of it, so the moderator chose to decline it (but it's not a big deal seeing the comment).

Mods handle a lot of flags each day, so you want to help them to the max by providing as direct information as possible.

Flag again with more info, as Jon commented:

> You can't flag the same post for the same reason more than once... however, the "other" reason is exempt from that.

Comment: You can't flag the *same post* for the *same reason* more than once... however, the *other* reason is exempt from that... so you can flag *other* on the *same post* as much as you want... obviously, just don't over do it though...